# “Is not recognized or is not accessible” error, when creating a Table

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, namespaces

I have been trying to do the same table like in the example but in the windows phone: 
http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2010/11/15/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol.html

I have downloaded the project and I have copied every class:
-GridItemsControl
-GridUtils
-PhantomPanel
After this I have changed the namespace of this classes to the "project.Tables"

Than I have declared in the xaml page 
xmlns:table="clr-namespace:project.Tables"

After doing this everything is fine except the parts with line:

The error is :"is not recognized or is not accessible" Do you know the solution to this problem?

Here is sample code from xaml page:

```
 <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ItemsControl table:GridUtils.ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Grid table:GridUtils.ItemsPerRow="3">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                </Grid>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <table:PhantomPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Item}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Quantity}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                    <Line Stroke="LightGray" StrokeThickness="1"
                      VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                      X1="0" X2="1" Y1="0" Y2="0"
                      Stretch="Fill"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                                </table:PhantomPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: at which xaml line you are getting this prob..

Comment: <ItemsControl table:GridUtils.ItemsSource="{Binding}" and                   <Grid table:GridUtils.ItemsPerRow="3">

Answer (score 0):

Zimas the link you are following is mainly for wpf and silverlight application but you are trying it for wp it's good but there may be a issue that some things that's is used in this link may not be supported in windows phone so just check out that . And also if want to do something like this in windows phone start it from scratch . do not copy code directly..hope this helps you..